# In Gate driver, high side is active but low side is drawing current

Tags: power-electronics

[image: Sheet]

I set up the circuit with an IR2104 IC and IRF3205 MOSFET last time, the circuit worked properly at first, I changed the pertinax with the MOSFETs, and my load started to draw 6.5 A while it was normally 5.5, and the low side gets very hot and draws 1 A current, I thought there was solder paste, I cleaned it and it improved a bit. Still running can anyone help

Comment: Hello there. What are the supply voltages? Input signal? The schematic could use some net/node names so we can discuss it properly. What is the load? (A... sounder? On a half bridge?) Do you have a PCB or breadboard layout? Oscilloscope to measure waveforms?

Comment: By pertinax, do you refer to the brand of single-layer paper based PCBs? If you're building a half-bridge at some switching speed, it would be very challenging. Please post your layout and oscillograms.

Comment: If the supply voltage of the IR2104 integrated is 15 volts, there is a lamp fed with 12 volts and I am switching with 16 KHz, it was not a problem at first, but after I changed the mosfets to a cleaner pcb, I had something like this and I can't fix it, I cleaned the mosfets with isopropyl alcohol, I cleaned the whole circuit, but I still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I found some of the problems and now I have only one problem. While the high side is active, my low side mosfet generates heat, what do you think?

Comment: Any progress on posting layout and oscillograms?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by progress.

Comment: IRF3205 needs a lot of gate charge current. It is possible, that it needs too much time to turn Q2 off while Q1 is turning on. The reverse transfer capacitance (211 pF) can slow down the low side turn off. So there may be a short shoot through condition in each switching cycle. Try a lower PWM frequency, a lower value for R2, a larger value for R1 or a stronger gate driver IC. Too long wires between the gate driver and the FETs can also mess up a proper turn off of Q2.

Comment: Can I switch a 1 mega ohm load